# Good background for PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, advice

What is a recommended background for graduate level PDE ? My school uses Evans ' PDE book. The PDE I class will cover first 4 or 5 chapters. Any contributing opinion will be appreciated.

(My background is : Cal 1-3,baby Real analysis, baby ODE, baby Linear Algebra.)

Comment: It really depends on how your Prof presents. IMHO your background is enough to tackle the graduate level PDE homework-wise. A comprehensive understanding needs time, the technique and way of thinking is very different from the math you have already learned.

Comment: Thanks Cao, from the students currently taking it, I heard that they have to do many proofs.

Comment: Yes, there is gonna be many proofs. However, the entry-level graduate pde course won't have many constructional proof (like proving different modes of convergence in real), many exercises on Evans are "relatively" easy.

Answer (score 2):

Basic theory of one complex variable and ordinary differential equations (ODE). No prior knowledge of partial differential equations theory is necessary.